# Authentication credentials are missing from twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I have this code

```
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String username="twitterapi";

   ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
   cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
    .setOAuthConsumerKey("zRQs******yDLJuQ")
    .setOAuthConsumerSecret("W368******************DsWya56uk")
    .setOAuthAccessToken("124529**************EQ2XAfAQShzSWExwMoOS")
    .setOAuthAccessToken("UiH**********************k6UuCPveirdF");

 TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
 Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

    User user = null; 

         try {
             user = twitter.showUser(username); 
         } catch (TwitterException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(Twitter_Final.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    if (user.getStatus() != null) {
       out.println("@" + user.getScreenName() + " - " + user.getDescription());
    } else {
        // protected account
        out.println("@" + user.getScreenName());
    }
```

But i get this the kwown error message "Authentication credentials are missing. See http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html for the detail."

I have read similar questions here but i cant see where the problem in my code is. Can you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `ConfigurationBuilder`, you are setting `OAuthAccessToken` twice but never `OAuthAccessTokenSecret`:

Just change your code to:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
           cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey(YOUR_KEY)
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret(YOUR_SECRET)
            .setOAuthAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN)
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
```

It would work!

Comment: I have the same issue saying credentials missing; I created a configuration builder and set consumer key and consumer secret. then once I acquire the accessToken, I set it on the twitter instance and attempt to make a tweet post. I then get that error